# Evaluating $\int^{4}_{1} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}-7\right)^2} dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was trying to find arc-length of $x = \sqrt{y}-7y$

So basically right now I am stuck with this

$$\int^{4}_{1} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}-7\right)^2} \,\mathrm dy$$

$$\int^{4}_{1} \sqrt{50+\frac{1}{4y}-\frac{7}{\sqrt{y}}} \,\mathrm  dy$$

How do I integrate further? I'm kinda stuck

Comment: Did you try $y=x^2$?

Comment: the main equation is $x = \sqrt{y}-7y$

so I think $y=x^2$ would be harder. Plus question wants in dy

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your integral as $\displaystyle\int_1^4\frac{\sqrt{200y-28\sqrt{y}+1}}{2\sqrt{y}}dy$, so $u=\sqrt{y}$, $du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}dy$ gives

$\displaystyle\int_1^2\sqrt{200u^2-28u+1}du=$ $10\sqrt{2}\int_1^2\sqrt{\left(u-\frac{7}{100}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{100}\right)^2}du.$

Now let $u-\frac{7}{100}=\frac{1}{100}\tan\theta$ to get

$\displaystyle\frac{10\sqrt{2}}{100^2}\int_{u=1}^{u=2}\sec^{3}\theta d\theta=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1000}\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\sec\theta\tan\theta+\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)\right)\right]_{u=1}^{u=2}$

where $\sec\theta=100\sqrt{u^2-\frac{7}{50}u+\frac{1}{200}}=\frac{10}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{200u^2-28u+1}$ and $\tan\theta=100u-7$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\arcsinh}{\operatorname{arcsinh}}$Using the first suggestion, i.e. $y=x^2$ to change the variable to $x$ we have $\int_1^4\sqrt{50+\frac{1}{4y}-\frac{7}{\sqrt{y}}}dy=\int_1^2\sqrt{\frac{1+(7-100x)^2}{50}}dx$. Now choose $u=7-100x$ so that you have a "standard" integral involving $\sqrt{1+u^2}$: use $\arcsinh$ to do a new change of variable. You will then obtain $\int_1^4\sqrt{50+\frac{1}{4y}-\frac{7}{\sqrt{y}}}dy=\frac{-930\sqrt{173}+1930\sqrt{745}-\sqrt{2}\arcsinh{93}+\sqrt{2}\arcsinh{193}}{2000}$.